# Creating sequential model using keras/python and CSV file but getting bad accuracy

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

i want to build a classifier, but i'm having trouble finding sources that can clearly explain keras functions and how to go about doing what i'm trying to do. i want to use the following data:

```
         0    1    2        3          4       5    6     7
0     Name  TRY  LOC   OUTPUT     TYPE_A   SIGNAL  A-B  SPOT
1    inc 1    2   20   TYPE-1    TORPEDO   ULTRA    A   -21
2    inc 2    3   16   TYPE-2    TORPEDO     ILH    B   -14
3    inc 3    2   20  BLACK47    TORPEDO    LION    A    49
4    inc 4    3   12   TYPE-2  CENTRALPA    LION    A    25
5    inc 5    3   10   TYPE-2      THREE    LION    A   -21
6    inc 6    2   20   TYPE-2        ATF    LION    A   -48
7    inc 7    4    2  NIVEA-1        ATF    LION    B   -23
8    inc 8    3   16  NIVEA-1        ATF    LION    B    18
9    inc 9    3   18  BLENDER  CENTRALPA    LION    B    48
10   inc 10   4   20    DELCO        ATF    LION    B   -26
11   inc 11   3   20    VE248        ATF    LION    B    44
12   inc 12   1   20   SILVER  CENTRALPA    LION    B   -35
13   inc 13   2   20  CALVIN3     SEVENX    LION    B   -20
14   inc 14   3   14  DECK-BT  CENTRALPA    LION    B   -38
15   inc 15   4    4  10-LEVI    BERWYEN     OWL    B   -29
16   inc 16   4   14   TYPE-2        ATF     NOV    B   -31
17   inc 17   4   10     NYNY    TORPEDO     NOV    B    21
18   inc 18   2   20  NIVEA-1  CENTRALPA     NOV    B    45
19   inc 19   3   27   FMRA97    TORPEDO     NOV    B   -26
20   inc 20   4   18   SILVER        ATF     NOV    B   -46
```

i want to use columns 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7 as input and the output would be 3 (OUTPUT).

the code i currently have is:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

df.drop('Name', axis=1, inplace=True)

obj_df = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).copy()
# print(obj_df.head())
obj_df["OUTPUT"] = obj_df["OUTPUT"].astype('category')
obj_df["TYPE_A"] = obj_df["TYPE_A"].astype('category')
obj_df["SIGNAL"] = obj_df["SIGNAL"].astype('category')
obj_df["A-B"] = obj_df["A-B"].astype('category')
# obj_df.dtypes
obj_df["OUTPUT_cat"] = obj_df["OUTPUT"].cat.codes
obj_df["TYPE_A_cat"] = obj_df["TYPE_A"].cat.codes
obj_df["SIGNAL_cat"] = obj_df["SIGNAL"].cat.codes
obj_df["A-B_cat"] = obj_df["A-B"].cat.codes
# print(obj_df.head())
df2 = df[['TRY', 'LOC', 'SPOT']]
df3 = obj_df[['OUTPUT_cat', 'TYPE_A_cat', 'SIGNAL_cat', 'A-B_cat']]
df4 = pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=1, sort=False)

target_column = ['OUTPUT_cat']
predictors = list(set(list(df4.columns))-set(target_column))
df4[predictors] = df4[predictors]/df4[predictors].max()
print(df4.describe())

X = df4[predictors].values
y = df4[target_column].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=40)
print(X_train.shape); print(X_test.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5000, activation='relu', input_dim=6))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# build the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=150)
```

i can't figure out why this is the result i'm getting:

```
Epoch 20/20
56/56 [==============================] - 4s 77ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 1.8165e-04
```

i also can't seem to find any answers related to this problem. am i using keras functions incorrectly? is it the way i'm coverting object type to integers? assuming there are 1250 outputs, how would i fix the layers? any tips or help would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: You have 3 fully interconnected Dense layers with 5000, 1000 and 500 neurons which in total is 2.5*10^9 neurons in the model. You input data gets spread over this vast number of neurons and you have so few data points that they barely make any difference on the result. What you need to do is to drastically reduce the number of neurons in Dense layers. And I mean *drastically*. Maybe like (20, 10, 5) or something like it.

Comment: hi, thanks for that very insightful information. however, that simply sped up running the program and the outcome is the same.

Comment: Have you tried some more conventional classifiers like SVM or Random Forest? Maybe your label is not related to input variables? Also how many classes do you have in the "output" category? And how many data points in total?

Comment: i have not looked into svm or random forest, but i can look into that. there are 1250 outputs and 5000 data points (rows?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments it seems like a clear case of model underfitting - you have too little data for the size of the model itself. Rather than playing around with the sizes of layers, just try SVM or RandomForest classifiers first and see if it's even possible to get any reasonable classification with your data. Also with this amount of data neural network is hardly ever a good choice.

So do this instead:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

import pandas as pd

df = blablabla # This is your data
X = df.iloc[:, [i for i in range(8) if i != 3]]
y = df.iloc[:, 3]

X = pd.get_dummies(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, min_samples_leaf=5, n_jobs=-1)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = rf.predict(X_test)

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
```

If this works and can make some predictions then you can go ahead and try to tune your sequential model.

**EDIT:** Just read your comment that you have 1250 class labels and 5000 samples in total. This is likely not going to work with most classifiers. Too many classes and too little sample support.

Comment: thank you for this answer. it was very helpful. i will obviously look more into this answer and what i'm looking at, but right of the bat, any idea what this error means? ```TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_samples_leaf'```

Comment: Sorry, it should be `min_samples_leaf`. It's been a long day today.

Comment: totally understandable lol. i got another error, ```ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')```. i'm going to look into this code so i can figure out the errors and get a better idea of the functions. thank you for your help though.

Comment: Oh, then you probably need to run `df.dropna(inplace=True)` in the beginning. You might lose a few records though.

Comment: i see. so if i'm getting ```ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.``` does that mean i don't have a viable dataset?

Comment: Which function/method is this error from?

Comment: i added ```df.dropna(inplace=True)``` right after ```df = pd.read_csv('X', delimiter=',')``` and the error came

Comment: It looks like you have missing records in every row and as a result all the data gets removed. You can add an option `subset=[column_names]`  into `dropna` and in place of column_names specify names of columns that you want to use in your classification.

Comment: great. thank you so much for walking me through the solution and being patient. now, i'll just have to work on understanding the code better and figuring out how to improve the accuracy (0.15198863636363635)